# How can I print True or False as "pass" or "fail"?

Tags: python, boolean

I am making a piece of simple code in Python that uses a boolean logic test to assess whether the mark entered is a pass or fail. I have managed to get the print function to show the result of the boolean test, but I want to display the word pass or fail dependent on the outcome of the test (which is a `simple >=65` is a **pass**, the *rest* is **fail**).

Please could someone let me know how I can achieve this? (instead of the output showing True or False I want to display Pass or Fail)?

Code:

```
number1 = int (input('please enter mark: '))

if number1>=65:
    number1result= True
else:
    number1result= False

print ("the result is", number1result)
```

Comment: change True for pass, and False for fail

Comment: In the future, please try to make your question's title *unique to the individual question*. We could have thousands of questions that are completely different from each other all with the title "Quick help on python"; it doesn't do anything to help someone find a question that already answers the specific problem they're having. (If we do our job right, people can find the information they need already here, instead of needing to ask new questions at all! See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ for more background).

Answer (score 4):

You should store a variable with the wanted word and then print it like this:

```py
if number1>=65:
    number1result = 'Pass'
else:
    number1result = 'Fail'

print ("the result is", number1result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number1 = int (input('please enter mark: '))
result = "is not OK"
if number1 >= 65:
    result = "is OK"
 print ("the result is ", result)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The one with one liner if condition:

```
number1 = int (input('please enter mark: '))
res='The result is '
res += ('pass' if number1>=65 else 'fail')
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an if else inline in such simple cases

```
mark = int(input('Please enter mark: '))
result = 'Pass' if mark >= 65 else 'Fail'
print('The result is:', result)
```

in fact it can be all a one liner (not that this is beautiful, but just as an example...):

```
print('The result is:', 'Pass' if int(input('Please enter mark: ')) >= 65 else 'Fail')
```